# What is the difference between PEF and PTF bioplastics?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, polymers, plastics

I am trying to research single use plastics replacements, and wanted to explain how PEF and PTF are a good choice. Although as I am researching I can't find clear information about them, also how they differ as article label them as the same. What are they? And how do they differ in an environmental standpoint?

Comment: Can you spell out the acronyms? Or is that part of your question?

Comment: Polyethylene furanoate (PEF) and polytrimethylene furandicarboxylate (PTF)

Comment: Looks like only one more methylene group in monomer, so not much of a difference. FYI better add info you did find to the question and make it more specific, if you don't want it getting closed.